# qt compiler error on instantiating class

Tags: qt, class, compiler-errors, instantiation

I am having a problem compiling dialog.h, the compiler complains that QHostAddress::Any is not a type, and expected identifier before numeric constant.  (both on the second to last line of dialog.h).

Can someone tell me why this won't compile?  I'm instantiating the server object, and passing parameters that the server constructor expects...i thought...

dialog.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include "server.h"

class QLabel;
class QPushButton;

class Dialog : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QLabel *statusLabel;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
    Server server;
};
```

server.h:

```
class Server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Server(QHostAddress listenAddress, quint16 listenPort, QObject *parent = 0);
    QHostAddress hostAddress;
    quint16 hostPort;

protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor);

private:

};
```

dialog.cpp (partial)

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), server(QHostAddress::Any, 4000)
{
```

server.cpp (partial)

```
#include "server.h"
#include "clientthread.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
Server(QHostAddress listenAddress, quint16 listenPort, QObject *parent = 0)
    : hostAddress(listenAddress), hostPort(listenPort), QTcpServer(parent)
{
}
```

---

Note code above updated.  Now compiler complains:

Expected ')' before 'listenAddress' on the constructor definition of Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the Server object as a Dialog class member variable and than define it in constructor. Here is how the Dialog class should look like:

dialog.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include "server.h"

class QLabel;
class QPushButton;

class Dialog : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QLabel *statusLabel;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
    Server server; // Declare server member variable.
};
```

dialog.cpp

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
:
    QWidget(parent),
    server(QHostAddress::Any, 4000) // construct server
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Michelle: ok, do it, when you call the constructor, but when you declare it, it should contains types as arguments, and not their actual value.

Comment: I thought that is what I did in the server.h above.  Can you provide a couple of lines of fixed code to show what to change?

Comment: Ok - I've updated the code as you suggest.  There is a new error (see original question above)...but I'm confused about something.  Since I declare 'Server server'in the dialog class definition, and then again 'Server server(x,x)' in the initialization for dialog constructor, am I creating 2 server objects?  (I'm new to c++ & QT)

Comment: @Michelle: actually declaring an object and initializing it doesn't mean you create two objects.